# React-native keyboard no comma on android Samsung devices in Text Input

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, samsung-mobile

I have a `React-native` app with `TextInput` and `KeyboardAvoidingView`. And everywhere it works well except android Samsung devices, especially Samsung A3. Because on this device the keyboard is appearing without a comma, but I need to use it on the screen.

I already tried the steps from [this article](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12988), removed `autoCapitalize="none"` from the `TextInput` component, but it is not working for me.

Can somebody recommend how can I solve it please.[[image]

```
 <TextInput
            style={textInput}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent' editable={!props.disabled}
            keyboardType={keyboardType} 
            autoCorrect={false} selection={state.position}
            value={state.value} onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
            onFocus={this._onFocus} onBlur={this._onBlur}
            autoFocus={autoFocus}
          />
```

Comment: use this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12988#issuecomment-407550185

Comment: it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

How about using

`keyboardType = {'numbers-and-punctuation'}`
in textInput

This is yout text Input

```
const alphaNumericRegex =  /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;

 <TextInput
          ref={ref => (this.panNumber = ref)}
          onChangeText={val => this.checkAlphaNumeric(val)}
          value={this.state.panNumber}/>



 checkAlphaNumeric = ( value) => {
    if (!alphaNumericRegex.test(value)) {
      if (this.state.panNumber.length == 1) {
        this.setState({ [panNumber]: "" });
      }
      Toast.show({
        text: "Only alphabets and digits are allowed.",
        position: "top"
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ panNumber: value });
    }
  };
```

Comment: but i need just numbers and comma, not all symbols

Comment: Use a regex which will auto delete the special characters other than comma

Comment: like this regex(^\d+$)? where should i put it can you tell me please my dear friend

Comment: Use this on change text, if it passes the condition then set the state else do nothing

Comment: I don't understand how to do it. I have React-native TextInput element with filed keyboardType={'numbers-and-punctuation'}, and i need just numbers, comma and delete button on the keyboard. And where should i put regex expression?

Comment: As soon as you call `onChangeText` there while you set the state to store the value put a condition over there. See my answer I have updated

Answer (score 0):

During the work i have found the info that this bug is a software problem, and it is present mainly on the older Android models with API 5.0, the best solution for this bug to use Google keyboard.